# How can I pass files from IP restricted server to web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have clients that use our web site (asp.net) that they have to be logged into.
The web site is hosted on servers 1-2-3-4-5 and traffic gets redirected to those servers depending on loading.

Then I have server A which stores certain files and this server is IP restricted, only allowing servers 1-2-3-4-5.

Now, on server A, I want to store video files and pdf files which I want to make accessible to the client and embed in the web site. I do not want to store this in db - I want to store the files on the server.

Since server A only allows the IP from server 1-2-3-4-5, not the IP from the client I cannot access those files directly from the client side. I need to embed the files into the web site somehow, fetching the files using the IP from the web servers.
I cannot use i-frame since that uses the clients IP.

Any ideas on how I can access and use the IP from the server and pass that on to server A to fetch the files? Is it possible to use request.redirect or server.transfer?

Comment: Do you need to embed the files or is it enough to allow them to download the files?

Comment: What do you use for load-balancing of the load? Isn't is possible to make the reverse-proxy(if any) to access server A ? In the explained scenario the only solution is a proxy channel through one of the web servers. Using nginx for instance can do a better job.

Comment: I need to embed the files - stream the videos. I cannot let the users download the files.

Comment: I don't want to move the files or copy the files anywhere - I just want to be able to present them to the users...

Comment: Ok... new info... I do want to send the files to the client, I do not want to embed them or stream.. this was a misunderstanding from my part..

So yes, it is enough to allow them to download the files

Comment: Please edit your question, in order to clarify the stream vs. download requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NFS or Windows networking file sharing to allow the web servers to access the file store.

Or have the web servers send a WebRequest to the file store, then just send the file on to the client.

But no, you cannot use Server.Transfer to transfer to a different server, in spite of the name.

Comment: I ended up using a simple WebRequest to the file store to fetch the files and send the file to the client. Thanks a lot!